# select.poll ImportError when imported from celery

Tags: python, celery

When I try to start the celery worker with `./manage.py celeryd --loglevel=DEBUG` , it raise me an ImportError exception.

But if I put the line which raise the exception in the python interpreter:

```
>>> from select import error as SelectError, poll
```

It works without trouble. I don't understand what make the import fail in celery.

Here is the traceback:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/loaders.py:103: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn("Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 19, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/management/base.py", line 68, in execute
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/management/commands/celeryd.py", line 25, in handle
    worker.run(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celeryd.py", line 101, in run
    return self.app.Worker(**kwargs).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 123, in run
    self.worker_init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 174, in worker_init
    self.loader.init_worker()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 108, in init_worker
    self.on_worker_init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/loaders.py", line 108, in on_worker_init
    self.import_default_modules()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/loaders.py", line 111, in import_default_modules
    super(DjangoLoader, self).import_default_modules()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 103, in import_default_modules
    for module in imports | self.builtin_modules]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 90, in import_task_module
    return self.import_from_cwd(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 98, in import_from_cwd
    package=package)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/utils/__init__.py", line 398, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 93, in import_module
    return importlib.import_module(module, package=package)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "<my app path>/apps/tasks/crawl.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 3, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/reactor.py", line 37, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import default
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/default.py", line 50, in <module>
    install = _getInstallFunction(platform)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/default.py", line 44, in _getInstallFunction
    from twisted.internet.pollreactor import install
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/pollreactor.py", line 16, in <module>
    from select import error as SelectError, poll
ImportError: cannot import name poll
```